# tensorflow library addons import

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, kaggle

I'm trying to import the library of tensorflow-addons in Kaggle, but i got an error.

```
import tensorflow_addons.layers.InstanceNormalization  # Install tensorflow-addons

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[103], line 29
     27 #from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model #!pip install pydot
     28 from keras.utils import plot_model #!pip install pydot
---> 29 import tensorflow_addons.layers.InstanceNormalization  # Install tensorflow-addons

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_addons/rnn/nas_cell.py:30
     21 from tensorflow_addons.utils.types import (
     22     FloatTensorLike,
     23     TensorLike,
     24     Initializer,
     25 )
     26 from typing import Optional
     29 @tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package="Addons")
---> 30 class NASCell(keras.layers.AbstractRNNCell):
     31     """Neural Architecture Search (NAS) recurrent network cell.
     32 
     33     This implements the recurrent cell from the paper:
   (...)
     53     TensorShape([30, 4])
     54     """
     56     # NAS cell's architecture base.

AttributeError: module 'keras._tf_keras.keras.layers' has no attribute 'AbstractRNNCell'
```

I tried the following command:

```
#!pip install keras --upgrade
#!pip install tensorflow==2.15.0 --upgrade
#!pip install tensorflow-addons==0.23.0 --upgrade
```

!python -m pip install tensorflow-addons